# I received this error: TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I have received an error that: TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable. How do I go about it?

````
Bike_share_casual = Bikeshare_all[Bikeshare_all.member_casual == 'casual']

Bike_share_member_p = Bike_share_member(['start_hour','Weekday']).ride_id.count().unstack().T.reindex().reindex(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])
Bike_share_casual_p = Bike_share_casual(['start_hour','Weekday']).ride_id.count().unstack().T.reindex().reindex(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])```
````

Comment: Please give more information about Bike_share_casual object?

Comment: Bike_share_casual is a dataframe I was creating for the casual members from the main df - Bikeshare_all. The Bike_share_casual_p, further groups it to two columns. It happened I only needed to add a .groupby - Bike_share_member.groupby(['end_hour','Weekday'])

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I added a groupby:

Bike_share_member_p = Bike_share_member.groupby(['start_hour','Weekday']).ride_id.count().unstack().T.reindex().reindex(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])
Bike_share_casual_p = Bike_share_casual.groupby(['start_hour','Weekday']).ride_id.count().unstack().T.reindex().reindex(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])